# SQLite : DELETE on multiple WHERE criteria from query

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database where I need to delete records from a many-to-many table, based on query results where 2 criteria for each row must be met.

As an example, take 2 tables :

```
    oldEvents              <select_query>

user_id  | event_id       qry_user_id  | qry_event_id
---------+----------      -------------+-------------
       1 | aaa                      2  | aaa
       2 | aaa                      3  | bbb
       2 | bbb                      1  | ccc
       3 | bbb
       1 | ccc
       3 | ccc
```

From table oldEvents, I want to delete each row that appears in the query, so as to end up with:

```
    oldEvents             

user_id  | event_id   
---------+----------   
       1 | aaa       
       2 | bbb         
       3 | ccc
```

Until now, I use a cumbersome DELETE query that concatenates the qry_user_id and qry_event_id, and uses them in an EXISTS sub-clause :

```
DELETE FROM oldEvents
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT user_id||event_id AS deleteCombo
   FROM oldEvents
   WHERE deleteCombo IN
   (
      SELECT qry_user_id||qry_event_id
      FROM
      <select_query>
   ) 
)
```

It works, but is hardly readable, and wouldn't scale once more variables enter the scene.

I can't repeat the select_query inline in an AND-clause, because it is, itsself, a rather complicated query (triple-JOIN).

I could write the query data to a temporary table, but would rather not do that.

Anyone a suggestion on how to write a DELETE that accepts multiple WHERE criteria from a query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your query inside a `CTE` like this:

```
WITH cte(user_id, event_id) AS (
  <your query here>
)
DELETE FROM oldEvents
WHERE (user_id, event_id) IN (SELECT user_id, event_id FROM cte);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/veQFs2iDkdyDUfKHzFhg4/1).
Results:

```
SELECT * FROM oldEvents;

| user_id | event_id |
| ------- | -------- |
| 1       | aaa      |
| 2       | bbb      |
| 3       | ccc      |
```

Comment: Works like a charm !

Tried it on my large query, and worked from the first time right.

And learned at the same time about how the "( user_id, event_id )" allows filtering on unique tuples. Thank you, @forpas !